# libCurl gives unsupported protocol on a script running as cron job

Tags: c++, c, email, curl, cron

Here is my situation: I have an sh script that writes some data to text files then calls a pre-built c++ binary that processes these text files and uses libCurl to send an email. Under the user that created the script and the binary everything is working fine, the email is delivered perfectly. Something goes wrong when executing the script under the cron daemon. Permissions-wise, the script and binary have 777 and the text files have 666. I have created another user and tried executing the binary it gave me the following error:

```
* Protocol smtp not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Unsupported protocol
curl_easy_perform() failed: Unsupported protocol
```

After the cron period passed the shell gave a message something like `You have a new mail in/var/spool/mail/$USER`, that file contains the same message.

Executing `curl -V` on both users:

```
curl 7.48.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.48.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the libcurl your cron job is using is the same as that your program is using when it succeeds. I can't tell you how many times I've ran into a situation where my program was using /usr/local/lib and discovered the hard way that a cron job hits /usr/lib. I had two builds of libcurl, the OS supplied in /usr/lib without some protocols enabled (like smtp), and my sudo-dev-installed version in /usr/local/lib for example. Best of luck.